# Bash autocomplete in ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh, autocomplete

It seems that bash doesn't want to autocomplete commands (what's annoying me right now is not autocompleting apt-get) when I'm logged into my machine from SSH. Is there some setting that will allow bash to autocomplete inside an ssh session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: `source /etc/bash_completion` should do the trick (run it in the shell within the SSH session).

Long story: in order for bash completion to work, you have to tell `bash` how to complete each command's arguments.  This requires a long sequence of invocations of the `bash` built-in command `complete`; therefore, they are usually collected in a separate script (or several ones in `/etc/bash.complete.d/*`) that loads them all.

Being a regular shell script, you can always load the `bash_completion` in any shell [startup script](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_63.html) (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bashrc`)

Further reading:

- section *Programmable Completion* in the man page `bash(1)`
- help text for the `complete` command (run: `help complete` in `bash`)

Comment: Great, that works. Can you explain why you have to do this? What about an SSH session does bash not like auto-completing. Is there a way to get this to do it for every ssh session? At least for a particular user (me)?

Comment: @Falmarri updated answer with the more info; does this answer your further questions?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, yeah